# Adding Elements to AWS Route 53 JSON

Tags: json, jq, amazon-route53

I've been attempting to programmatically update the AWS Route 53 DNS records, so I've been using jq to update the following JSON file;

```
{
  "Comment": "Update 'A' record for drivepoc.biz zone file",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "www.domain.biz.",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 60,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "123.123.123.123"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the existing entry `"Value": "123.123.123.123"` needs to remain, but needs to have additional entry of `"Value": "456.456.456.456"`.  The nearest I got to do this was:

```
cat a_record.json | jq '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords |= .+ ["Value: 456.456.456.456"]'
```

but this puts it outside the braces and the quotes are wrong;

```
 "ResourceRecords": [
   {
     "Value": "52.18.219.57"
   },
   "Value": "456.456.456.456"
 ]
```

Instead of what is required;

```
 "ResourceRecords": [
   {
     "Value": "52.18.219.57"
   },
   {
     "Value": "456.456.456.456"
   }
 ]
```

Can anyone give me any tips please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding an object to that array, not a string. Create an object to be inserted.

```
.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords += [{Value:"456.456.456.456"}]
```